# Am I able to stop a loop by calling another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question can I stop this function from another function... let me just show you:

```
var s = 50;
function myfunction(){
  for (i = 0, i < s, i++){      
    var saythis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hi");
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(saythis);
  }
}
```

Then I want to use another button that calls the function stop to stop that loop, is that possible?

Comment: `break;` statements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: `break;` would exit the loop (and return as nothing follows the loop) if that's what your asking, `return;` would return.

Comment: It is not very clear what your question means.  Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: `break` isn't called from another function......

Comment: *"Then I want to use another button that calls the function stop to stop that loop, is that possible?"* No. JavaScript has the concept of *run to completion*. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the edit to the question by the OP have changed the question so much that answers originally posted are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I want to use another button that calls the function stop to stop that loop, is that possible?

No. JavaScript has a concept called *run-to-completion*:

> #### "Run-to-completion"
>
> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that **whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates)**. This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it can be stopped at any point to run some other code in another thread.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: This question got me thinking about whether or not you could use a label on the loop and `break label` from outside the function (not that it's a good idea, just if it was possible). From what I can tell, scoping is pretty tight with labels and you couldn't access a label across functions.

Comment: It's not possible to interrupt a function from the outside. I.e. no other code can run if the function is executing. The loop can only be broken by code that is invoked by the function itself (and yea, labels wouldn't work).

Answer (score 1):

If all your operations are synchronous (which it appears they are), then you cannot stop that function from outside the function because no other Javascript other than what is called from within that function will get a chance to run while the `for` loop was running.

Your `for` loop will stop sooner if the `s` variable is set to a smaller value.  So, if some function that is called from within the `for` loop changes the value of the `s` variable, then the `for` loop will stop sooner.

There are many ways to stop your `for` loop from within the loop itself.  You can use a `break;` statement to break out of the loop.  Or, you can `return` from the function within the loop.  Or, you can implement a separate flag that is another condition your loop checks.  There are lots of ways to code your loop to stop when you want it to from within the function that the loop exists in.  But, your question asked about stopping the loop from some other function.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag, and turn it on when you want to stop the loop from outside:

```
var s = 50;
var stop = false;
function myfuntion(){
    for (i = 0, i < s || stop, i++){        
        var saythis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hi");
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(saythis);
    }
}

function stop_it() {
    stop = true;
}
```

Comment: How do you modify `stop` in a synchronous function? IOW, where/how do you call `stop_it()`?

Comment: @KevinDTimm -  you could call a function from within the for loop and stop it from there

Comment: Reading the OP, how do you do that from a button press?

Comment: @KevinDTimm - The button part wasn't in the original question

Answer (score 0):

If you have other structures within your loop, your loop will wait until those structures complete before exiting the loop. What you can do, is create some conditions within that loop to force an exit.

Comment: reading the question, the OP wants to trigger on a button press